# List in Function in Python Read as Multiple Objects

Tags: python

I have a function that looks like this:

```
class Question:
    Ans = "";
    checkAns = 0;
    isPos=False;
    def Ask(Q, PosAns):
        checkAns=0;
        Ans = raw_input("{} ({})".format(Q,PosAns));
        while(checkAns<len(PosAns) and isPos!=True):
            if(Ans==PosAns[x]):
                isPos=True; #if it IS a possible answer, the loop ends
            checkAns+=1;
            if(checkAns==len(PosAns)):
#If the loop goes through all the possible answers and still doesn't find a
#match, it asks again and resets checkAns to zero.
                Ans = raw_input("{} ({})".format(Q,PosAns));
                checkAns=0;
        return ("Good Answer");

ques = Question();
print(ques.Ask("Do you like to code?",["Yes","No"]));
```

First off, the point of this function is to take in a question (Q) and all the possible answers (PosAns), and if the user puts in something that is not one of the possible answers, then the function will simply ask again.

Every time I run it, however, it says that the Ask() function can only handle two parameters and that I've given it three (note that YesNo has two strings inside). Why does it read the list's objects instead of taking the list as a parameter? How can I make it take the list as the parameter?

I do recognize that the way I code is roundabout and strange to most people, but it's just the way things make sense to me. I'm more interested in the answer to my question than a new way to write the whole function (I'm still working on it).

Comment: You're missing `self`.

Comment: Exactly. That's the reason for the error. The Ask method is missing the 'self' parameter

Answer (score 0):

You missed the 'self' in method declaration. Every class method (except static methods) require first argument to be `self`. self is implicily passed so doesnt show up in our method calls.
self can be used to refer the the other attributes of call like `isPos`, `checkAns` and `ans` variables in this example

Though one thins I wann't able to figure out what is `x` here
`if (Ans == PosAns[x])`

```
class Question:
Ans = "";
checkAns = 0;
isPos = False;

def Ask(self, Q, PosAns):
    Ans = raw_input("{} ({})".format(Q, PosAns));
    while (self.checkAns < len(PosAns) and self.isPos != True):
        if (Ans == PosAns[x]):
            isPos = True;  # if it IS a possible answer, the loop ends
        self.checkAns += 1;
        if (self.checkAns == len(PosAns)):
            # If the loop goes through all the possible answers and still doesn't find a
            # match, it asks again and resets checkAns to zero.
            self.Ans = raw_input("{} ({})".format(Q, PosAns));
            self.checkAns = 0;
    return ("Good Answer");
```

Comment: The 'x' isn't supposed to be there, actually, I was making this function because I usually just write out the entire thing every time I ask a question. I copied most of the code over from part of another project, so the 'x' is from somewhere else. Thank you!

Comment: @CharlieBiggs In that case you can up vote it and accept as answer